How to implement a mosaic font effect for Qt components (such as QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit) in a disabled state?
I’m working on an industrial system and need to implement a mosaic font effect for Qt components (like QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit) when they are in a disabled state. The font effect should resemble the old Unix system style from the 1990s. It’s not just a matter of downloading a specific font, but rather eliminating the spacing between font pixels to create the effect. I’ve tried several fonts but haven’t found one that achieves the desired result.
Specifically, I want to apply this effect to standard Qt components (e.g., QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit) so that they display the mosaic style when disabled. The effect should be compatible with the current UI style and avoid modern or overly complex font styles.
Currently, I’m unsure how to implement this via code. If QPainter is required for custom drawing, I have a general idea of how to approach it, but I’m unsure how to apply it to existing component styles for this retro effect.

Is there a known Qt style or method to achieve this mosaic effect?

If QPainter is required, are there any example codes or ideas for how to implement it?


The font style should appear above the image as shown:

Additional Information:

Operating System: Windows 11

Qt Version: Qt 6 with MSVC2019 (2022)

Development Environment: Laptop with a screen resolution of 3072x1920 (the target hardware is likely 1920x1080)

Screen Scaling: The screen scaling rate could be 100%, 125%, 150%, or 200%.



"How do I do XyZ" is not a good question to ask on SO

Just looks like dithering to me.

A ton of extra code to reproduce a style from 30+ years ago is not going to be a very popular question anywhere. Are you able to draw text with QPainter with the desired effect in an efficient manner (<1ms)? If you were to add the snippet to your question, people can probably tackle your question (and delete their downvotes).

Dithering. It wasn't "mosaic effect" or something back then and not Linux only, windows and macos had same. it was a consequence that text was drawn on 16, 32, 64, 256 color platforms which didn't had enough grays. Technically I could get such effect with qt3 and qt4 on similar video adapters (can't call them GPU really). If you need a retro effect, qt6 got a dithering effect available. It's not advisable to use as it looks bad, with smaller resolutions and never was a feature, rather a side-effects of limitations.

You may use a QProxyStyle based, but it completely depends on the base style implements rendering. There is no guarantee that it could work for all widgets, even though starting from drawItemText might be a good start.

To illustrate the comment from @musicamante, an example of situation where it does not work (I have created a draft on my computer since my previous comment) is when I set the color of a QPushButton in a stylesheet. To be clear, without the style sheet (or if the style sheet simply change e.g. the font size), it works. My code draws the CE_PushButtonLabel but I have no (confirmed) idea why this same control is not drawn when the color is altered.

@Atmo The reason is that whenever a style sheet is set on a widget, Qt internally creates a specialized QStyleSheetStyle (which is private) based on the current widget style, therefore almost any override done on the proxy style would be fundamentally skipped, because the various drawPrimitive, drawControl, etc will be completely done by the QSS style. Yet, most styles often rely on drawItemText() of the base style (including QSS style), so overriding it is an option; there's only no 100% certainty that it would be called by advanced styles, including the Windows/macOS default ones.

@Atmo I've done some tests, and drawItemText() seems to be called consistently even when using style sheets, at least using the common windows and fusion style (and the oxygen and breeze style on Linux). I cannot check on macOS style nor on a real windows style, not to mention the latest Windows11Style (which is still known to be a bit buggy). A dithering may be achieved by setting a QPen with a QBrush that uses the Dense4Pattern before calling the painter's drawText(), but it's still a bit fuzzy, especially for vertically thin fonts, making text difficult to read sometimes.

What you are describing with QPen/QBrush is exactly what I've done in the code, indeed. But I was doing it on drawControl, not drawPrimitive and that only works sometimes as I explained. But I can give it a try when I have time; or feel free to answer.

@Atmo As said above, drawControl and similar functions would never be called whenever the QSS affects the widget appearance (eg: borders). But it's not just that: even relying on drawItemText() calls only works for widgets specifically using QStyle to draw text, leaving out all widgets using rich text or text interaction in some way: any primarily text based widget relies in some way on QTextDocument features, and painting is never achieved through QStyle: QTextEdit and QPlainTextEdit are obvious candidates, but even the simpler QLineEdit and QLabel are out of the question.

@Atmo In fact, it's possible to achieved the same as above even by only setting the appropriate palette roles, as long as using a style that properly uses palette brushes (not colors), without a proxy style and with a clean stylesheet: with the "fusion" style, it would be enough to alter the app palette (eg: p = app.palette()) by doing p.setBrush(p.Disabled, p.WindowText, QBrush(p.color(p.Normal, p.WindowText), Qt.Dense4Pattern)), repeating the same for ButtonText and Text palette roles, and reapplying the palette to the app. Yet, QSS will ignore that, as QTextDocument widgets would.

@musicamante: I can't confirm what you say. My sample (with only drawControl) has a button for which a style sheet changes the font size and it works. But if I change the font color, it does not. But in the first place, I agreed with you that guaranteeing the pattern will be apply looks like a very difficult thing to do, to say the least.

@Atmo There's a reason for that: drawing functions are not fundamentally affected by the font, at least for what they're directly concerned about (the font metrics). A different font normally affects only size related functions (eg. sizeFromContents()), meaning that drawControl() and similar functions would eventually base their calls on the option font or rect (which have been previously been accounted for), because font aspects have been considered before that. The style is responsible of drawing, so the draw functions are therefore overridden in order to be aware of color changes.

tl;dr

Is it possible?
Yes.

Is it easy?
No.

Even if it's difficult, once achieved, would it be "transparently" applied?
If, by that, we mean being able to create a widget as we would normally do (eg.: lineEdit = QLineEdit()), including being able to use Designer based files, then, again, no.

Is it worth trying?
Generally no, but it depends on how much time you can/want to spend on it (and it would be a lot) and your headache threshold limit.


Explanation
In Qt, widgets are mostly drawn using QStyle based classes and their functions. QStyle is treaded almost always as an abstract class, and most QStyles are based on QCommonStyle and the private QWindowsStyle (which is not what is primarily used by default in modern Windows systems). Also, modern Windows and macOS systems use private styles that cannot be [easily] subclassed or managed/altered, even completely ignoring the given QPalette.
When a QApplication is created, it has a specific style that is normally common to all widgets. Each widget class then implements, in its paintEvent() override, how it would draw its contents (but also uses other QStyle functions for other purposes, such as defining its size hints based functions).
While, for non primarily-text-based widgets, QStyle provides functions to draw their text (for instance, the text of a button), most widgets use more complex aspects to draw their texts.
In the standard QtWidgets library, there are actually few classes that usually consider text to be drawn "as is", with the most common being QAbstractButton based classes (QPushButton, QToolButton, QRadioButton and QCheckBox) and those using them (eg. QDialogButtonBox).
That function is drawItemText().
This could drive us to believe that creating a QProxyStyle subclass implementing drawItemText() would be enough.
Even in the above cases, though, the painting of those widgets is still achieved using QStyle functions, meaning that if a style does not use the drawItemText() function above to draw the widget text, the proxy style approach would be completely pointless, because the style is probably painting the text on its own, probably using QPainter functions.
That's not all. Text centered widgets do not use QStyle functions to draw at all (at least, for actual painting). This includes:

QTextEdit (and the inherited QTextBrowser);
QPlainTextEdit;
QLabel (if no rich text, word wrapping or style sheets are involved);
QLineEdit;
any QLineEdit involved class, including QAbstractSpinBox classes and editable QComboBoxes;

This is because the above classes use the QTextDocument APIs for drawing contents, which may eventually use QStyle functions only for generic aspects (eg: the text cursor width), but then they always draw their contents on their own with complex and internal calls that are directly based on QPainter functions and completely disregard QStyle calls.
The only safe (but not 100% reliable) way to achieve what you want would be to completely write your own QStyle (not just a QProxyStyle subclass) and implement all functions eventually relying on either the style's proxy or a virtual "base style" it's based upon.
Which means overriding (and completely writing almost from scratch) the behavior of, at least:

drawComplexControl();
drawControl();
drawItemText();
drawPrimitive();

and that's considering all related QStyle::ComplexControl, QStyle::ControlElement and QStyle::PrimitiveElement related painting.
Ok, but how could this be achieved without a custom style?
There are various levels of how this can be done.
If we only consider basic widgets like buttons, and as long as no color based style sheets are involved, we could simply alter the application palette.
For instance, we could get the default palette and change the brush of WindowText, ButtonText and Button by creating a QBrush that is based on the given color for the Normal palette role, but uses a Qt::Dense4Pattern brush style.
This won't work for QSS widgets that alter colors (or complex widgets and/or their sub controls), though.
We may even try to install an event filter on the Qt application and check for QEvent::Paint events, then temporarily draw contents of a given widget on a QPixmap using some dithering filter and, draw back the content based on that pixmap, but that would obviously affect performance, and a lot.
This is still not 100% reliable, as styles may add "hidden" widgets or animations that could complicate things or result in ugly rendering.
The above may not even always be valid. For instance, if you use QWidgets in a QGraphicsScene using QGraphicsProxyWidget, the scene could potentially create garbled renderings.
And all this does not even consider the further complexity caused by High DPI screens (and their different implementations across various OS) or system/user font scaling.
Ok, but it's cool and fun, isn't it worth doing it?
No.
And if you have a supervisor/senior asking for that as a mandatory requirement, then you have three options:

ask for a substantial raise;
ensure that what they ask requires:

a huge amount of time;
they cannot push its resolution;
it may be buggy, even years after a possible "stable" release;


quit that job, as the importance of what they're asking is almost pointless or they're not able to understand the implications of their requests;

